# Can I use AVPlayerViewController with AVPlayerLooper?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, avkit

I want to use `AVPlayerViewController` to display the video but it should be in auto-play mode.
Previously I was using AVPlayer for that and listening to the `.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification but I wonder if there is a better way? eg. using AVPlayerLooper for instance so I don't have to use that `.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` anymore

I wrote something like this but it is not working - I have a black screen with video controls - probably because AVPlayerViewController does not have any playable content...

```
struct VideoPlayerQueuedView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  let videoUrl: URL
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
      let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
      let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
      
      // Create an AVPlayerItem from the videoUrl
      let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl)
      
      // Create an AVPlayerLooper with the queuePlayer and the playerItem as the template item
      let playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
      
      // Set the player property of AVPlayerViewController
      playerViewController.player = queuePlayer
      
      return playerViewController
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
      // Update the video player if needed
  }
}
```